# How to update dependencies of dependencies using Yarn

Tags: npm, material-ui, yarnpkg, react-admin

I use react-admin v3.1.4 and I tried to upgrade to v4 but it was to hard. So, while trying to go back to the previous version, I found a problem that didn't run. This is a problem caused by the version of mui being different from before the update attempt. I'm struggle with this for few days.. please help!

#### Question

**So, What I want to do is to change nested `@material-ui/icons` version.**
I want to change react-admin's @material-ui/icons version `v4.11.3` to `v.4.2.1`(previous verion)

This is part of my dependency.

```
├─ @material-ui/icons@4.2.1
└─ react-admin@3.1.4
   └─ @material-ui/icons@4.11.3 => ToDo : change to v4.2.1
```

I already tried these things.

1. remove `node_modules` and `yarn install`
2. `yarn upgrade --depth 5`

Here's my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@elastic/react-search-ui": "^1.7.0",
    "@elastic/search-ui-app-search-connector": "^1.7.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.3.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.3.3",
    "@redkiwi/shared": "^1.0.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "final-form": "4.18.5",
    "final-form-arrays": "3.0.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.1",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "lerna": "^3.20.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.8.2",
    "ra-core": "3.1.2",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^3.0.2",
    "ra-i18n-polyglot": "^3.2.2",
    "ra-language-english": "^3.2.0",
    "ra-ui-materialui": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-admin": "3.1.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.3.3",
    "react-final-form-arrays": "^3.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "redux-form": "7.4.0",
    "shallowequal": "^1.1.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add resolutions to your `package.json`

```json
"resolutions": {
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1"
}
```

More details:
[Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)